# Show repeated values on a simple MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this two users:

> id = 143 
> user = User 1
>   ---- 
> id = 91 
> user = User 2

and this simple query:

`SELECT name FROM users where id IN (143,143,91);`

It two results:

```
User 1
User 2
```

Is there any way to return the repeated values as well? My desired output would be:

```
User 1
User 1
User 2
```

Comment: No. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: IS id is unique or primary key

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT name FROM users where id = 143
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM users where id = 143
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM users where id = 91
```

One simple query will do not return the same `143` twice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, creating another table inserting all the ID you want to extract:

```
CREATE TABLE TUSERS (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO TUSERS VALUES (91, 'User2');
INSERT INTO TUSERS VALUES (143, 'User1');

CREATE  TABLE TMP01 (ID INT);
INSERT INTO TMP01 VALUES(143);
INSERT INTO TMP01 VALUES(143);
INSERT INTO TMP01 VALUES(91);

SELECT A.*
FROM TUSERS A
RIGHT JOIN TMP01 B ON A.ID=B.ID;
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME
143 User1
143 User1
91  User2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IN` list is simply used for filtering existing rows.  If you want all values, then an outer join is recommended.  You can produce the `IN` list on the fly:

```
select u.name
from (select 143 as id union all
      select 143 union all
      select 91
     ) ids left join
     users u
     on u.id = i.id;
```